# How I can make auto refresh jwt tokens? Spring boot angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt

I have back on spring boot, jwt tokens storing in httpOnly cookie, how i can make auto refresh token? On back i have refresh tokens method

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create Angular `Interceptor` which will call refresh token endpoint if `HTTP request` returns 404 and user was logged in - you can store data if the user was logged (some boolean) in session storage.

If you get error on refresh token call you can clear the flag.

Comment: But how make call to refresh-token endpoint when token will be expired?